# How to convert a recursive function to use a stack?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, stack

Suppose that I have a tree to traverse using a Depth First Search, and that my algorithm for traversing it looks something like this:

```
algorithm search(NODE):
  doSomethingWith(NODE)
  for each node CHILD connected to NODE:
    search(CHILD)
```

Now in many languages there is a maximum depth to recursion, for example if the depth of recursion is over a certain limit, then the procedure will crash with a stack overflow.

How can this function be implemented without the recursion, and instead with a stack? In many cases, there are **a lot of local variables**; where can they be stored?

Comment: I find this question to have a small element of unintentional humor to it due to the fact that most programming languages (though not all) would use a stack internally for this. Of course, there's also the fact that for most languages, to hit the recursion limit with a depth-first search would require you to have either an extremely unbalanced tree or a very very very large one, considering that you'd need a depth of about 1000 and most, say, balanced binary trees have a number of elements equal to 2^depth - 1, which would mean, for that tree, you'd need 2^1000 - 1 elements before overflow.

Comment: And, of course, since a language may use a stack to implement the recursion behind-the-scenes anyway, whatever is causing the overflow in the recursive form may become a problem with the explicitly-using-a-stack version as well. (I don't feel that this is a bad question, though; I'm just feeling a bit out of it at the moment and am in a rambling mood.)

Comment: In fact my tree is very, very large, although with a large number of identical nodes. So the identical nodes are cached in a hash table but the tree is nevertheless very large.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You change this to use a stack like so:

```
algorithm search(NODE):
  createStack()
  addNodeToStack(NODE)

  while(stackHasElements)
      NODE = popNodeFromStack()
      doSomethingWith(NODE)
      for each node CHILD connected to NODE:
         addNodeToStack(CHILD)
```

As for your second question:

> In many cases, there are a lot of local variables; where can they be stored?

These really can be kept in the same location as they were originally.  If the variables are local to the "doSomethingWith" method, just move them into that, and refactor that into a separate method.  The method doesn't need to handle the traversal, only the processing, and can have it's own local variables this way that work in its scope only.

Comment: Maybe it is obvious, but if there is local state for the node, in addition to the local processing variables, then you simply add them to the definition of NODE.

Answer (score 4):

For a slightly different traversal.

```
push(root)
while not empty:
    node = pop
    doSomethingWith node
    for each node CHILD connected to NODE:
        push(CHILD)
```

For an identical traversal push the nodes in reverse order.

If you are blowing your stack, this probably won't help, as you'll blow your heap instead

You can avoid pushing all the children if you have a nextChild function

Comment: You typically blow your stack way, way before your heap...  Stack memory size is often restricted to a fairly low amount (ie: 1mb).

Comment: Yes, but if you are recursing enough to blow away a 1M stack, you are almost always doing something sufficiently wrong to blow away another 3 orders of magnitude with ease.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially you new up your own stack: `char a[] = new char[1024];` or for type-safety, `node* in_process[] = new node*[1024];` and put your intermediate values on this:

```
node** current = &in_process[0];
node* root = getRoot();

recurse( root, &current) ;**

void recurse( node* root, node** current ) ;
  *(*current)++ = root; add a node
  for( child in root ) {
    recurse( child, current );
  }
  --*current; // decrement pointer, popping stack;
}
```