# Deep recursion error

Tags: c, recursion, codeblocks

I have a problem with too deep recursion in c (I'm using Codeblocks). Around recursion depth of 73000 the message Segmentation fault (core dumped) is occurring. The deepest possible recursion depth is size*size (look at code for size). In my case size=500, so deepest possible recursion is 250000. The function that is run recursively is written below:

```
void sosedi(int *h, int spin, int k, int l, int rec, gsl_rng * r1){
rec+=1;


if(rec>70000) printf("%d\n",rec);
double tc=2.269185;
double  temp = tc*0.5;



*(h+k*size+l)=-*(h+k*size+l);
if(k!=size-2 && *(h+(k+1)*size+l)==spin  && pow(2.71828182845904523536, -2*J/temp) < gsl_rng_uniform (r1)  ){
sosedi(h,spin,k+1,l,rec,r1);
}
if(k!=1 && *(h+(k-1)*size+l)==spin  && pow(2.71828182845904523536, -2*J/temp) < gsl_rng_uniform (r1)  ){
sosedi(h,spin,k-1,l,rec,r1);
}

if(l!=size-2 && *(h+k*size+l+1)==spin  && pow(2.71828182845904523536, -2*J/temp) < gsl_rng_uniform (r1) ){
sosedi(h,spin,k,l+1,rec,r1);
}

if(l!=1 && *(h+k*size+l-1)==spin  && pow(2.71828182845904523536, -2*J/temp) < gsl_rng_uniform (r1)  ){
sosedi(h,spin,k,l-1,rec,r1);
}

}
```

I have been searching for a solution and have come across two solutions. First is to  write

```
--stack="some big number"
```

in project -> build options -> linker settings -> other linker options, but it doesn't work. 
The other option is to use ulimit -s unlimited. I know how to use it in terminal, but don't know how to use this command in codeblocks.

I am not sure recursion depth is causing this error, but the code works for size = 100 and size=200.
Thanks for help.

Comment: Read the [name of website](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow) carefully

Comment: I know this stack overflow, but there is a way to increase the stack. If anyone knows how to do it in Codeblocks, I'll be very happy.

Comment: If you're smashing the stack, consider an iterative approach instead. Most C compilers can't guarantee tail call optimization, so if you want to write safe code, I recommend you avoid recursion. You must be pushing in the order of megabytes on the stack for it to overflow. Just saying.... :)

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be a victim of stack overflow.

You should revisit your code logic and try to use some alternative to avoid or minimize recursion or use some technique similar to tail recursion which is optimized by many compilers.

You may also want to read [How to convert a recursive function to use a stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391285/how-to-convert-a-recursive-function-to-use-a-stack)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I solved the problem. I used setrlimit function. [Here](http://www.go4expert.com/articles/getrlimit-setrlimit-control-resources-t27477/)
is a very nice description on how to use it.