# Stack limit and recursive functions

Tags: c, recursion, linux-kernel, stack, stack-overflow

A C program uses recursion to find a property of a graph.  Large graphs can't be processed because the stack space is too small.  The program has to be recoded to use an explicit stack and a loop.

Should recursive functions check the input will "fit" in stack space first?

Is there an example in the linux kernel where a recursive function had to be replaced with 'explicit' recursion?

Comment: I think most times is nearly impossible to check if the input will fit in stack, as the input can be a very complex expression.

Comment: In a production environment recursion is kept to a minimum where the SO risk is almost zero. I doubt there is much recursion in the Linux kernel done on the CPU stack.

Comment: What is "explicit recursion"

Comment: @Mulliganaceous "explicit recursion" is implementing recursion using an explicit stack and a loop rather than using a recursive function that uses the process' stack (implicitly)  see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391285/how-to-convert-a-recursive-function-to-use-a-stack

Comment: I am not sure it helps in your case : consider [limiting the recursion depth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46022542/3992939)

Comment: How far are you out?  Woult it be easier to instruct the linker to allow a larger stack limit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Should recursive functions check the input will "fit" in stack space
>   first?

This is generally very difficult. The amount of stack memory required for each recursive call might be different when compiling the code using different compilers or different versions of the same compiler or using different compiler switches to compile the code. In fact, the function may require different amounts of stack memory in different calls depending on its control flow.

So if you think that there is a serious risk of overflowing the stack, you should convert recursion to iteration (potentially using an explicit stack) and/or limit the number of recursions/iterations.

> Is there an example in the linux kernel where a recursive function had
>   to be replaced with 'explicit' recursion?

Yes. A nice example of this would be the code that implements the resolution of symbolic links. [Prior to Linux 4.2](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.1.51/source/fs/namei.c#L1804), the code was recursive as follows:

```
link_path_walk -> nested_symlink -> follow_link -> link_path_walk
```

`link_path_walk` is the main name resolution function. If it detects a symbolic link, it calls `nested_symlink`, which may in turn call `link_path_walk` recursively. To mitigate stack overflow in the kernel, `nested_symlink` performs the following check:

```
if (unlikely(current->link_count >= MAX_NESTED_LINKS)) {
    path_put_conditional(path, nd);
    path_put(&nd->path);
    return -ELOOP;
}
```

Each task descriptor has a `link_count` field, which is increased each time `nested_symlink` is called. If it exceeds a fixed threshold (`MAX_NESTED_LINKS` is 8 in Linux 4.1.51), the whole operation terminates with an error.

Starting with Linux 4.2, the recursive code was changed into an iterative code with an explicit stack and the threshold was relaxed to 40. This [article](https://lwn.net/Articles/650786/) discusses the iterative code in detail.