# convert a recursive function with local state to use stack

Tags: javascript, recursion, data-structures, stack

I know how to convert simple recursive functions with a stack (like what is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391285/how-to-convert-a-recursive-function-to-use-a-stack)), however, some recursive functions have a tricky part that I don't know how to implement. Simpler recursive functions don't change the caller local variables (by caller I mean the function that calls itself) or in other words simpler recursive functions don't change their local variables based on the returned value from calling itself, but it becomes tricky when it needs to change that and I don't know how to do the same thing with stack implementation. Here is a simplified example:

```js
const obj = {
  src: {
    size: 0,
    children: {
      api: {
        size: 0,
        children: {
          api_2: {
            size: 0,
            children: {
              'file1.js': {
                size: 2,
              },
              'file2.js': {
                size: 2,
              },
            },
          },
          api_1: {
            size: 0,
            children: {
              'test1.js': {
                size: 1,
              },
              'test2.js': {
                size: 1,
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
};

const recursive = (object) => {
  if (object.children) {
    const currentChildren = object.children;
    Object.entries(currentChildren).forEach(([, child]) => {
      object.size += recursive(child);
    });
    return object.size;
  } else {
    return object.size;
  }
};

recursive(obj.src);

console.log(obj.src.size);
console.log(obj.src.children.api.size);
console.log(obj.src.children.api.children.api_1.size);
console.log(obj.src.children.api.children.api_2.size);

// Output: 6 6 2 4
```

If my question is confusing, just implementing this recursive function with a stack can help me understand my problem a lot.

Comment: *What* recursive function? What "caller local variables"?

Comment: Are you talking about converting recursive function calls to recursive loops?

Comment: @DaveNewton by recursive function I mean any recursive function (a function that calls itself), like what I have in the example (its name is `recursive` by accident). By _caller_ I mean the function that calls itself, and by its local variables I mean the variables in that _caller_ call stack.

Comment: @Teemu I'm not sure what is a recursive loop, I simply don't wanna use recursion because of reaching **maximum call stack**. I want to implement the recursion with my own stack. Like what is described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391285/how-to-convert-a-recursive-function-to-use-a-stack) question.

Comment: "_Simpler recursive functions don't change the caller local variables_" In general, any function can't change the variables which are local to its caller. In the example you seem to have a recursive function, but it doesn't fire the said error. If you want to change the recursion in the example into nested loops, and maintain your own stack, Reed's answer in the post you've linked seems to explain how to do it very thoroughly, specifically when including in the first comment.

Comment: @Teemu yeah ofc it can't change the variable which is local to its caller. I should have said it like _"Simpler recursive functions don't change their local variables based on the returned value from calling itself"_.

Comment: Ah, okay, to do that, is exactly what Merlyn states in their comment: "_if there is local state for the node, ... add them to the definition of NODE_". For example you can create an object named `locals` and add the local property values to it, and `locals` to the stack object (NODE).

Comment: @Teemu this should probably be the way, but when I implement it I'll lose the state hierarchy, In my example the hierarchy of data is important. Let me try again on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a depth first search with a stack by popping the last element with their parent and add visited nodes again if it has children. The `flag` prevents to add it again. Thsi approach visits the nodes twice, one for searching for most depth node and another to update `size` property.

```js
const
    update = object => {
        const
            stack = [[object]];

        while (stack.length) {
            const [o, p, flag] = stack.pop();
           
            if (!flag && o.children) {
                stack.push([o, p, true]);
                Object.values(o.children).forEach(q => stack.push([q, o]));
            } else if (p) p.size += o.size;
        }
    },
    obj = { src: { size: 0, children: { api: { size: 0, children: { api_2: { size: 0, children: { 'file1.js': { size: 2 }, 'file2.js': { size: 2 } } }, api_1: { size: 0, children: { 'test1.js': { size: 1 }, 'test2.js': { size: 1 } } } } } } } };

update(obj.src);

console.log(obj.src.size); // 6
console.log(obj.src.children.api.size); // 6
console.log(obj.src.children.api.children.api_1.size); // 4
console.log(obj.src.children.api.children.api_2.size); // 2

console.log(obj.src);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This is awesome and probably what I wanted. It's theoretically not possible to do this with traversing nodes for once? right? Then choosing between doing this with **stack**  or **recursive** becomes a trade-off of speed and reaching maximum call stack (or maybe space).

Comment: you need to visit all nodes in both direction, one for getting the children and another to assign `size`.